# Request failed with error code "ENTITI_ERROR.ATTRIBUTE.INVALID.DUPLICATE"

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing-certificate

My IOS App is already being uploaded to the Testflight on App Store Connect by some other developer. Now I am trying to upload it on Testflight and I am getting following errors:

1. App record creation failed due to invalid attribute and reason "The SKU you entered has already been used"
2. App record creation failed due to invalid attribute and reason "The BUNDLE ID you entered has already been used"
3. App record creation failed due to invalid attribute and reason "The app name you entered is already been used for another app in your account"

Please help with this issue as I have tried everything and not getting any solution.

Answer (score 2):

All errors itself is describing issue having with your App. SKU, Bundle Identifier and App name already registered on App Store. You have to change these three parameters to upload your app on TestFlight.

The bundleIds resource represents the app's unique identifier that you can register, modify, and delete. You need a bundle ID before you can assign capabilities with the Bundle ID Capabilities resource or create a provisioning profile with the Profiles resource.